# Text Being Modified - Special Chars

Tags: c#, xslt, google-search, google-search-appliance

I have an item in my XML that returns a tag like this: `<MT N="firstName" V="Nataša"/>`

I am then displaying this in these two ways:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstName" select="MT[@N = 'firstName']/@V"/>
<img src="{$headshotUrl}" alt="{$firstName} {$lastName}" />
<xsl:value-of select="$firstName" />
```

The end result that is being output is Nataa, and is dropping the accented S completely in Chrome. Looks like I get different results in different browsers, but none of them are displaying the character correctly.

The page is set to `UTF-8`, so there should be no issue there.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The transformation is being applied in C#, as follows:

```
string qs = "http://" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleIP"] + "/search?" + query;

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(qs);

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(XSLToLoad))
{
     XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

     //Load the XSL stylsheet into the Transform object
     transform.Load(XSLToLoad);

     //Create a StringWriter object to hold the result
     StringWriter sw;
     sw = new StringWriter();
     //update parameter if needed
     XsltArgumentList xslArg = AddPageParams();

     //Perform the Transform
     transform.Transform(xpathDoc, xslArg, sw);

     //Assign result to asp label
     litResults.Text = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you apply transformation?

Comment: Updated the original question with the code for transformation.

Comment: What do you mean by "The page is set to UTF-8"? Where do you see that? What are the different results you get in different browsers? E.g. if they don't all drop the š then we can look at what they are displaying to learn about the encoding being used.

Comment: If you add C# code to output all the codepoints (character values) in `sw` in hex, what are the codepoints around "Nataa"? This will tell you if the problem is in/before the transform, or after it.